# How can I test my ePub files in Android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, ebook-reader, ebooks, epub

I have installed the Android emulator and everything is going fine. But I don't know how to test my ePub in it. This is actually the main reason I installed Android emulator and SDK, to test out my ePub's.

Target Name: Android 1.4
Platform: 4.1
API Level: 16

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you use Android emulator for that? I suppose different epub readers will give you different results...

Comment: What exactly are you testing?

Answer (score 1):

Install different ebook readers like Aldiko / Moon+ Reader etc and see whether your ePub displays as intended.

Comment: How? Because I tried going to https://play.google.com/ and installing Aldiko. And it refused to do so. It says it does not recognize the device or something.

Comment: Don't you have an Android device? Is that why you're using the emulator? Get the APK from the dev's site and install it from within the emulator. http://www.aldiko.com/download.html and http://www.moondownload.com/zthMoonReader.apk

Comment: Nop I don't. And my friends testing ePubs also don't have Androids, they have IPads and IPhones.

Comment: In any case, you can get the APKs from the links in my prev comment and install them within the emulator.